# How to show/hide a div based on ajax response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

Right now I have two webservices; one is my main app, and the other is returning JSON data.  I am trying to show/hide a div based on a value from the JSON data that I get as a response to a post.  What/where is the best way/place to add this logic?  Here's some code of what I have so far.  The ajax call is working fine, and I'm able to render a message based on the response, but I'm not sure about the logic for showing/hiding the div based on the ajax response.  Thanks.

controller action:

```
def checkItemProperty() {
  def service = new MyService()
  def itemInstance = new Item(params)
  String itemProperty = itemInstance.itemProperty

  if (service.checkItemCondition(itemProperty)) {
    render "Property is true"
  }
  else {
    render "Property is false"
  }
}
```

gsp head snippet:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
<g:javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showHideDiv").hide();
    $("#someClickableLink").click(function(){ $("#showHideDiv").show(); });
  });
</g:javascript>
```

gsp body snippet:

```
<g:formRemote name="testForm" url="[action:'checkItemProperty']" update="[success: 'message', failure: 'error']">
  <g:textField name="itemProperty" value="${itemInstance?.itemProperty}" />
  <g:actionSubmit type="submit" name="add" value="Check" />
  <span id="message"></span>
  <span id="error"></span>
</g:formRemote>

<div id="showHideDiv">...</div>
```

**Edit:**
service method:

```
def checkItemCondition(String itemProperty) {
  def test = new RESTClient('http://localhost:8081/test/')
  def testResponse = test.post(path : 'test.json', body : [status:itemProperty, source:'httpbuilder'], requestContentType : URLENC)
  def jsonObject = testResponse.getData()
  return jsonObject['itemResponse']
}
```

**Edit:**
how I constructed the JSON data for the above controller action:

```
def test = [:]
test.value = true
test.text = 'Property is true'
render test as JSON
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Where is your Javascript code that submits the AJAX call?

Comment: @Katana314 look the g:formRemote docs: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/formRemote.html

Comment: @Ernie You want to show or hide "showHideDiv" depending on the return of formRemote?

Comment: @Katana314 I added the service method, but as I mentioned before, I'm getting the ajax response the way I expect.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do.  The ajax return value is essentially a boolean that is being used in the controller.

Comment: @Ernie James answer is what you need :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to change your controller:

Controller:

```
render [value: true, text: "Property is true"] as JSON
```

or

```
render [value: false, text: "Property is false"] as JSON
```

GSP (Remove the `update` attribute):

```
<g:formRemote ... onSuccess="handleResponse(data)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function handleResponse(data) {
$("#message").html(data.text);
if (data.value) {
 $("#showHideDiv").show();
}
else {
 $("#showHideDiv").hide();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The render lines you provided causes a compilation issue, so I tried something a little different:
"render(builder: 'json') {
  value: true
  text: "Property is true"
}"

but I'm not convinced this is working either.

Comment: The compilation error being:
No map entry allowed at this place

Comment: Also it seems like the controller action doesn't get fired without the update attribute.  I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Show all of the code you have relating to this with the updates I provided. If you aren't hitting the action then your URL in the ajax call is incorrect.

Comment: I made an edit for how I put the JSON data together.  Still not sure why I got that compilation error before; I figured what you had should have worked.  Anyways, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your existing post I can approximate:

```
$.post(yoururl, yourdata, function(postresultdata){
     $("#showHideDiv").show();
});
```